# Using Java to find simple Active Directory Information

Tags: java, user-interface, powershell, active-directory

This is my first post, so please be gentle.

I've recentley started using Powershell at work to change AD groups, find AD information etc. but I'm lacking the GUI that I like so much about Java.

Is there a simple way (or example of code) whereby I enter a target hostname and I'm returned with the details I ask for. AD memberhsip groups, account info etc?

My Java knowledge isn't as great as my Powershell so as much help as possible would be really apprechiated.

Thanks

Comment: If you need java code you have to add tag for it!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to perform AD queries using java?

Comment: I think OP meant he would like a JAVA GUI app for his powershell script.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking to how make AD queries using JAVA

Comment: Why not just do the GUI in PowerShell too? textbox, button and datagridview or perhaps a browser control to display a HTML report. You could create it via win forms or WPF.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking for a full java GUI to query Active-Directory, you may have a look to [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

If you want to query AD just using java, here is a sample code :

```
class TestAD 
{ 
  static DirContext ldapContext; 
  public static void main (String[] args) throws NamingException 
  { 
    try 
    { 
      System.out.println("Début du test Active Directory"); 

      Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11); 
      ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"); 
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://societe.fr:389"); 
      ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "ldap://dom.fr:389"); 
      ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=administrateur,cn=users,dc=societe,dc=fr"); 
      ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=jean paul blanc,ou=MonOu,dc=dom,dc=fr"); 
      ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pwd"); 
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl"); 
      //ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "simple"); 
      ldapContext = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv); 

      // Create the search controls          
      SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls(); 

      //Specify the attributes to return 
      String returnedAtts[]={"sn","givenName", "samAccountName"}; 
      searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts); 

      //Specify the search scope 
      searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); 

      //specify the LDAP search filter 
      String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user))"; 

      //Specify the Base for the search 
      String searchBase = "dc=dom,dc=fr"; 
      //initialize counter to total the results 
      int totalResults = 0; 

      // Search for objects using the filter 
      NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls); 

      //Loop through the search results 
      while (answer.hasMoreElements()) 
      { 
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next(); 

        totalResults++; 

        System.out.println(">>>" + sr.getName()); 
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes(); 
        System.out.println(">>>>>>" + attrs.get("samAccountName")); 
      } 

      System.out.println("Total results: " + totalResults); 
      ldapContext.close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
      System.out.println(" Search error: " + e); 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      System.exit(-1); 
    } 
  } 
}
```