# Querying active directory to get attribute on android

Tags: android, azure, active-directory

Hi (i'm new to this so you'll need to forgive me)

My end goal is to be able to grab an attribute from Microsoft azure active directory for use in my app. The issue being that while i have done a fair amount of research i'm still at a loss of how to achieve my end result.

I have found that Microsoft has an API of sorts that allows authentication with azure AD but i'm unable to find any information as to how i query an attribute.

Possible solutions I've looked into:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-android (Microsoft's android AD API)
- [Using Java to find simple Active Directory Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212179/using-java-to-find-simple-active-directory-information) (this isn't a possible solution as i need azure integration as the AD server isn't outward facing).

I'm sure that the solution to this isn't a complex one but i would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. I don't have much experience with AD which is why i'm struggling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could learn how to integrate Azure AD into an Android app from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-android) . You could call [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) or [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog) to access AAD resource :

1. To call Microsoft Graph API/Azure AD Graph API from Android Native Client application , In `Settings` blade of that app in azure portal, select Required Permissions and select Add. Locate and select `Windows Azure Active Directory`(Azure AD graph api )/Microsoft Graph(microsoft graph api) , add the appropriate permissions under Delegated Permissions .
2. To get access token With ADAL for android :

   ```
   mContext.acquireToken(MainActivity.this, resource, clientId, redirect, user_loginhint, PromptBehavior.Auto, "", callback);
   ```

   resource is required and is the resource you're trying to access.So you need to set that value to "https://graph.windows.net" if you want to call Azure AD graph api , and "https://graph.microsoft.com" if you want to call Microsoft Graph Api.

Comment: As i need to query an attribute called employeeId would i change that code to something like this?: `mContext.acquireToken(MainActivity.this, "https://graph.microsoft.com", clientId, redirect, employeeId, PromptBehavior.Auto, "", callback);`

Comment: No , that method is help you get the access token , with access token you could call microsft graph api(if resource is https://graph.microsoft.com) to get information , for example , user profile, please read [authentication with Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview)