# java sending email using Ms exchange server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

HI I have this code working, to send email´s using Ms exchange server .

The problem is that it uses the sender email address  and is pwd to do the authentication.

Now the system admin, tells me that due to security enforcement rules ,  authentication must be done with username and password , no email and password .. 
at the moment could´t  find any solution for this ... my working code :

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host.trim());
props.put("mail.smtp.port", port.trim());
props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.quitwait","false");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.class);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","true");
props.put("mail.debug","false");
props.put("mail.mime.charset","utf-8");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
          {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(properties.getProperty("emailFrom"),properties.getProperty("emailPassword"));
          }
         });
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify your code by [getting rid of the socket factory settings and the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  I don't understand what change you're supposed to make with authentication.  You can supply whatever value you want when authenticating - maybe it looks like a user name, maybe it looks like an email address - JavaMail doesn't care.  On the other hand, your server very much does care.  What are the actual requirements for your server?  Does it want you to send a user name or an email address when authenticating?

Comment: HI thank you , the problem is that I need to send emails "outside" like email´s XXX@gmail.com or XXX@live.com using exchange server ,  since I can´t logon using a username and pwd into exchange , the exchange server will not relay the message to gmail or live.com

Comment: You need a mail server that will relay.  If your Exchange server refuses to relay, and you can't reconfigure it to relay, you need to find a different mail server.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly it's a setting on Exchange server to allow SMTP client to use user name or email address for authentication.

There are several ways to get it work.

1. On Exchange server, normally email address follows a fixed name convention rule which we call Address Policy. In some organizations email address is converted from username. That means it's possible that you can get the user name from the email address. For example, if my user name is dongmao, with the address policy my email address can be:

   username@domain.com -> dongmao@domain.com

   username.mail@domain.com -> dongmao.mail@domain.com

   So just ask the system admin is there is a way to figure out the user name. More details about email address policy can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171(v=exchg.150).aspx) through I don't think you will be interested if you are not an Exchange man.
2. If you are dealing with Microsoft Exchange, then I assume you are in an environment with Microsoft Active Directory. Both email address and username are actually AD attributes and both of them are unique so it's easy to query username by email address or vice versa.

   I don't have the java code at hand to query AD, but there are quite a lot on the Internet, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212179/using-java-to-find-simple-active-directory-information) can be a good one. Just pay attention to the LDAP query string.The attribute name in AD of email address is **proxyAddresses** which is a multi-value attribute. The username attribute is **samAccountName**.

Let me know if you have further questions.